# How to determine count of a value in a column based on constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a large dataset and I was wondering how to calculate the most common occurrences of a certain attribute's value.

For instance, let's say I have a hypothetical table called Cats. I insert the following values into it:

```
Create table Cats (Cat_ID int, Cat_name varchar(max), Cat_Hometown varchar(max), Gender varchar(max), Birth_Year int)

INSERT INTO CATS (Cat_ID, Cat_Name, Cat_Hometown, Gender, Birth_year)
VALUES (1, 'Blue','Boston','M', 1980),
(2, 'Steamer','Plymouth','F', 1999),
(3, 'Stack','Newton','F', 1980),
(4, 'Overflow','Boston','M', 1978),
(5, 'CatorDog','Allston','F', 1999);
```

What if I want to determine the **most common** city for female cats in the year 1980? How would I do so? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Conditional aggregration on the birth year? `Select cat_homeTown, sum(case when birth_year <=1980  and gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt from cats where gender = 'F' and birth_year <= 1980 group by cat_hometown order by cnt desc`?

Comment: Why have you used the < operator? I just want to know the values for the year 1980

Comment: because the requirement was unclear.  You said "female cats in the year 1980" you didn't say born, so I assumed alive  so to me any cat born before 1980 for a city was eligible, remove it if the requirement is born in 1980  You also didn't say wou wanted just one record so I ordered desc. on the count so the highest count would be at top so on down.

Comment: Do you think grouping by the hometown would help? Because we are trying to find occurrences of a certain hometown.

Comment: Yes that was in the comment

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query to do so.

`select Cat_Hometown, count(Cat_Hometown) as Cats_Count from Cats where gender='F' and Birth_year=1980 group by Cat_Hometown order by count(Cat_Hometown) desc limit 1;`

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Cats (Cat_ID int, Cat_name varchar(max), cat_hometown varchar(max), Gender varchar(max), Birth_Year int)

INSERT Into #CATS (Cat_ID, Cat_Name, Cat_Hometown, Gender, Birth_year)
VALUES (1, 'Blue','Boston','M', 1980),
(2, 'Steamer','Plymouth','F', 1999),
(3, 'Stack','Newton','F', 1980),
(4, 'Overflow','Boston','M', 1978),
(5, 'CatorDog','Allston','F', 1999);

;with cat_count as (
select count(1) NumberofCats, Cat_Hometown from #Cats
where Gender = 'F' 
and Birth_year = 1980
group by cat_hometown
)

select Cat_Hometown from cat_count
where NumberofCats = (select max(numberofcats) from cat_count)
```

Comment: with doesn't work so well in mysql... or has that changed.